# Sync Video to Audio in SonyVegasPro13 with multiple anchors

Tags: vegas-pro, sync

I have a sample recorded with half speed at 60fps (for better quality later on), which is my video track.
Then I seperately recorded the audio track at normal speed.
I imported the video track into SVP13 and in its Properties I set the playback rate to 2.0000
When syncing the video to the audio at one point, it is out of sync a few moments later, as the audio and the video track don't match in there playbackrate.

Is there a way to set multiple anchors on the audio and video track and let SV sync these anchors together (with the priority on the audio track, so the sound does not get distorted and the video get adapted)?

Comment: Sample recorded using what? Does the video have a constant framerate? Use Mediainfo from https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo to find out if you don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

- Split your *Video* track into separate *Events*;
- Adjust the *Events* individually by dragging them along the timeline *and* stretching/expanding them;
- Overlap the adjacent *Events* so that there were no gaps;

---

## Long Answer

I find one of the most valuable features of Sony Vegas its ability to split the original tracks into *Events* and adjust them individually. As I wrote in [another answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/10713/2365), playing with Track's *Velocity* or *Velocity envelope* appears to be inefficient.

Also, no plugin will detect the best moments in timeline for transitions. Doing this manually seems a bit boring at the first glance, but it will certainly give you the best result.

[image: Vegas screenshot]
Full scale image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE3uF.png)

Note, this image shows splitting of a single track, but in your case it would be two *Grouped* tracks, one is *Video* and another one is *Audio*.

Here's how I would align Audio and Video tracks to accomplish your goal:

1. Decide what *Tracks* are to be adjusted. Since you probably have a high-quality *Audio* and you worry about any distortions, **let us assume your HQ *Audio* remains intact**. Moreover, since the video is filmed in double framerate, there's no worry of possible artifacts appear after adjustments.
2. So, place both Video and Audio tracks to the timeline.
   Note, if the Video track goes with some Audio, you will have **three** tracks:

   1. Video
   2. Its accompanying Audio (to be discarded in the future)
   3. A high-quality Audio
3. Make a temporary adjustment of *Audio* volume so that you could hear *both* Audio tracks. It can be 50% for each, or you may set them to left/right channel, depending on the nature of the audio. You will revert this at the end;
4. Find the **moments of any mismatches**. The best way to do is by finding drums or some other sharp sounds. Zooming *Tracks'* height will also be helpful as it lets you see the audio peaks on the histogram;
5. At each moment of mismatch, **split** the *Video* event (along with its accompanying sound since they are *Grouped*); Don't do it straight on the peaks. ½ seconds earlier is a better idea.
6. Shift the *Video* to right or left so that it matched;
   Note, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>dragging</kbd> ignores grid, markers, fade-in/fade-out marks, and all other time points that otherwise would cause "sticking".
7. Repeat for the rest of your composition;
8. Now, on the Video track, drag the left/right edges of each *Event* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>drag</kbd> them to change the playback speed of individual *Events*. Your final goal is to make the speed matched firmly.
9. Manage the overlap of the *Events*. Make sure you have standard *Fade* as your *Transition Effect*, not another fancy one. Make sure the *Transition* is not longer than ¼ of second (at 60 FPS, it would be 15 frames), or otherwise you get video artifacts.
10. After you complete, simply turn off the original low-quality *Audio* track.

Also note that the split points are best when the picture movement is minimal. For instance, if you have a drum player, the best would be when his/her hands are in the lowest point of hitting the drums, not raised.